# Rotate an image in Navigation Item titleView

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to rotate an Image in titleView of a Navigation Item below is my code

```
let arrImage = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow"))

arrImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

arrImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

navigationItem.titleView = arrImage
```

When root viewcontroller transitions to this view controller the image is rotated but as soon as the transition finishes the image gets rotate back to it's original position.

It seems that from some where something is calling identity on the Affine Transform that I did to the image

Can anyone help me in figuring out this strange behaviour or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Try putting the image view in a parent view. Make the parent view the `titleView`.

Comment: you can use your code in viewDidAppear() method. but the image would load bit late

Comment: @rmaddy strange if I add it to a button it doesn't work but if I add it to a UIView it stays at the correct place... can you point to any docs regarding this?